# Scrolling through FlatList in React Native does not provide Talkback message in Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, accessibility

I am using React Native's FlatList component. When user is scrolling through FlatList on Android with TalkBack on, it does not read "showing items ... to ... of ..."

On iOS, scrolling with Voiceover **does** give feedback (showing page x of y).

I'm wondering if this is a gap in react native's FlatList? Or am I missing some settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some conflicting for the talkback as mentioned in the [**Accessibility api**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html#accessibilityliveregion-android) but without a reference code its hard to debug the answer.

Here are a few points to note in the beginning -

- You need to have [accessible](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html#making-apps-accessible) elements so that the disable people might use it
- By default, all **touchable elements** are accessible.You can pass prop `accessible={true}` to make the view accessible. *It will wrap all its children to a single accessible component*
- Check if the screen reader is active using **[AccessiblityInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo.html)**

  *Your issue might lie here*

As mentioned

> In the case of **two overlapping UI components** with the **same parent**, default accessibility focus can have unpredictable behavior.

Therefore you might need to set [`importantForAccessibility`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html#importantforaccessibility-android) label to resolve this issue and can accept props `auto`, `yes`, `no` and `no-hide-descendants`

Comment: Talkback is able to read the elements on screen. I can loop through the elements and click on them and they announce the right things. However, if I scroll I don't get the announced update of which items are currently on the page. I tried playing around with setting importantForAccessibility and accessibilityLiveRegion, but neither helped :(

Comment: Can you try binding your `Flatlist` to a `PureComponent` as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) and add 1 ) `accessible={true}` on the `Flatlist` since it inherits `ScrollView props(which inherites view props)` and 2) `accessible={true}` on the `Flatlist` children views. Also please post a sample code (with a dummy array) so that i can test it.

Comment: Any suggestion please, have similar issue for inner screens for Android 6 only. After navigation Talkback doesn't play on inner screens when I tap any list item. List items are getting loaded dynamically from internet.